# What comes in 1 gallon jugs?

Tags: buying

At Walmart they sell wine in 3 liter jugs (Just shy of 1 gallon) For roughly $10 a piece, but 1 gallon jugs at roughly $15 a piece. Sadly, the mouth of these 3 liter bottles is exactly too small to fit your average bung designed for gallon jugs, making them only good for aging.

Is there any common store in the southwestern US that sells something like wine, apple juice, etc in a full gallon glass jug for cheaper than the glass bottles? I'm looking for stores like Aldi or Publix, that are pretty common in these parts of the US vs a small store that will likely not be in my area.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whole Foods has apple juice in a gallon jug. A #6 stopper will fit them.

[https://www.amazon.com/365-Everyday-Value-Organic-Concentrate/dp/B074VG4CMW/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B074VG4CMW)

Comment: Makes good hard cider, too.

Answer (score 2):

I use 1-gallon pickle jars, I have 2 of those and use them all the time, big wide-mouth metal lid that you can drill a hole through for a bung if desired, and easy to get a hand in to clean and sanitize.  I got mine from a friend, but I'm sure you can find big pickle jars at a discount store (such as Sam's Club or Costco or the like).

Comment: Would never have thought of using a pickle jar! Great suggestion!